# Resuming Repo sync operation when getting android's source code

Tags: android-source, repository

I followed the instructions [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and ran `repo sync` The issue is at this exact time my disk ran out of space accordingly. I have another computer and I wonder if I simply copy the .repo and run repo sync again will that work? Or is there any way out.

Comment: repo is just a small script. Why do not you want to repeat the procedure again on your new machine?

Comment: Bandwidth - Android source code is almost 10gb

Comment: As I understand you did not download all the sources in the first case. So I think that it's better to start downloading on your second computer. If you have downloaded all the sources on your first computer you can easily copy the folder with sources on your second computer.

Comment: Most of the sources -Almost 6gb of it. But not completely. Will it start downloading from the point where it left off if I use copy paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small research and here is my answer. As you may know AOSP consists of a lot of separate git projects and repo is a tool built on top of git commands to facilitate dealing with all these git projects. [This](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) webpage tells that `repo sync` command during the first time corresponds to `git clone` command. As far as I understand if git clone command is interrupted it is recommended to delete unfinished repository clone and start the command once again:

> When cloning a large repository (such as KDE, Open Office, Linux
>   kernel) there is currently no way to restart an interrupted clone. It
>   may take considerable time for a user on the end of a small pipe to
>   download the data, and if the clone is interrupted in the middle the
>   user currently needs to start over from the beginning and try again.
>   For some users this may make it impossible to clone a large
>   repository.

However, some users also ask how to correct unsuccessful clone and give some receipts how to do this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/mKtvYdCaZfY). The main point is to run the following commands:

```
$ git fetch
$ git rebase -hard
```

At the same time, if you run `repo sync` command for the second time it corresponds to commands for each project:

```
git remote update 
git rebase origin/BRANCH
```

I do not know git well and do not know the differences between the commands but to my point of view the commands perform similar actions. So my reccomendation is at first try to copy from the folder from one computer to the second and run repo sync command on the second computer once again. If it fails then remove the sources and start the process once again.

Also `repo forall` command can be useful for you if you decide to work with each git project separately.